# How to add validation in WordPress custom form in custom plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, validation, plugins

I've made a custom form and made a custom plugin of it to send email and store data into database, everything is working fine. I am using PHP mailer for sending email & using SQL query for storing data into my database table but
 issue is:
after every two minutes it is keep sending empty Email to my mail address and keep storing empty fields into my database.

I've used isset empty validation but it is not working here which prevents from storing empty data into database in PHP but not working in WordPress using custom plugin.

```
if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
$name = $_POST['name'];
 if(!isset($name) || empty($name)){
 $error[] = "Name is required";
 }
```

I am new in WordPress just started working here, please tell me how to prevent from storing empty fields into database or which validation/function should I use to prevent empty data fields in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I miss multiple things here, HTML form not posted also missing alot of functional things like how you submit this form. My opinion is that this question is not very clear.

Why your datafields are not stored? 
Are you sending empty forms or does this have to be attached to core function, provide more code so we can understand it.

You also really should check the docs of wordpress, especially this one for updating db records 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: i fixed it by adding if(!isset($error) || empty($error)){
 $to = "noumannazir400@gmail.com";  
 $headers = "From : "; 
    { //other code